# SortBy without index values in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

I'm returning a resource using sortBy :

```
$join=Account::with('actype','ledger')->get();
            $resource=GetMainLedgersResource::collection($join);
            $collection=collect($resource);
            $data=$collection->sortBy('description');
           //description is a field of Ledger model ,ie 'ledger' is the relationship function to Ledger model
return response()->json(['ledgers' => $data], 200);
```

when i run this in postman it works just fine but also printing index values with collection , like :

```
 "ledgers": {
        "85": {
             "id": 12,
            "account": "Direct Expenses",
            "account_type_id": 5,
            "ledger_id": 119,
            "alias": "AWS",
            "description": "AWS Hosting",
            "schedule_id": 12,
            "is_default": 0,
            "is_online": 0,
            "is_invoice": 0,
            "is_refund": null,
            "ledger_nature": 1,
            "status": 1,
           },
           ...
          }
```

i want to return response without the numbered index ,like :

```
 "ledgers": [
             {
                 "id": 12,
                "account": "Direct Expenses",
                "account_type_id": 5,
                     ...
                     },
                  ]
```

hope somebody could help :)

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
$join=Account::with('actype','ledger')->orderBy('description')->get();
$data=GetMainLedgersResource::collection($join);
return response()->json(['ledgers' => $data], 200);
```

Comment: doesn't work, because  _description_  is not in the `Account` model, its in the `ledger` model

Comment: 'description' which model's field?

Comment: 'description' is in ledger model

Comment: $join=Account::with('actype','ledger')->get()->sortBy((function($account, $key) {
          return $account->ledger->description;
        }));

use this

Comment: thats not working